# JavaScript getting array index from promise

Tags: javascript

The script below returns promise, there is an array inside it with two index, i want to get index=0 and index=1 separately and output them, how can i do it without using console.log?

```js
async function a1(callback) {
  var a = 2 + 2;
  return await [a, callback()];
}

async function a2() {
  var b = 2 + 3;
  return await b;
}
console.log(a1(a2));
```

[image]

---

My question for Artash Grigoryan

[image]

Comment: Well you can use `.then()` on the promise and get the result

Comment: Your code is awaiting numbers and arrays...? please create an actual [mre].

Comment: a) that code is nonsense b) what does "output without console.log" mean?

Comment: In general, if you have a Promise that resolves to an array, you a) await the promise b) access the array. I have no idea what you're asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript, async functions always return promise.

I am not entirely sure about your intentions here, but looking at your drawing I would assume that you need to add an extra `await` on lines 3 and 9.
This code should work for you:

```js
async function a1(callback) {
        var a = 2 + 2;
        return await [a, await callback()];
  }

async function a2() {
    var b = 2 + 3;
    return await b;
}
await a1(a2);
```

Reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: if i want to return value from function a1 to function a2, could you show me an example how to do it, please. Here an example ```function a()
  {
    var a1 = 2 + 2;
    return a1;
  }

  function b (inp)
  {
    var b1 = inp + 2;
    return b1;
  }

  b(a());```  but i want example with async/await + callback like mine example and like yours answer

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand why without `console.log`, but You can do this:

```js
async function main() {
  console.error(await a1(a2));
}

async function a1(callback) {
  var a = 2 + 2;
  return await [a, callback()];
}

async function a2() {
  var b = 2 + 3;
  return await b;
}

main();
```

Comment: Sir, i asked you question above, please take a look

Comment: Sorry, but I don't really understand Your question, I see only one screenshot with the response in your console, if the question is why you have the response in red, it's because of `console.error`, you can replace it with `.log`

Answer (score -1):

`a2` is an async function , so `callback()` wont be resolved here in this statement `return await [a,callback()]`.

You can check if the callback is of type [AsyncFunction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/AsyncFunction) , if so then you can wait for it to get resolved before returning the value

```js
async function a1(callback) {
  var a = 2 + 2;
  if (callback.constructor.name === 'AsyncFunction') {
    const m = await callback().then(val => val)
    return [a, m]
  }
  return await [a, callback];
}

async function a2() {
  var b = 2 + 3;
  return await b;
}
a1(a2).then(d => console.log(d))
```

Comment: why would you mix `async/await` and `Promise.then()` behaviors here?

Comment: @MaxLarionov  please check this 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#return_value